# Move TheSpaghettiDetective from local machine to Azure Container Instances

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-container-instances

I have clone TheSpaghettiDetective (https://github.com/TheSpaghettiDetective/TheSpaghettiDetective) repository and then use the docker-compose.yml to build it and it works great on my local machine. Now I want to push it to Azure Container Instances in a multi-container group, but can't get it working.

I tried using [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/tutorial-docker-compose) from Microsoft, but this project is a lot more complex.
The docker-compose file creates 4 containers that run, I couldn't figure out push them to Azure Container Registry with the tutorial, but was able to do so easily with the docker extension in VS Code.

Then when I tried deploy the images, I was able to get the docker context setup but the images wouldn't deploy. I think because they rely on the files I downloaded from github, to so I think I need to setup a file share in azure???

Where do I go from here? Is there no easy way to clone the repository into azure and use docker-compose up like I'm used to?

Answer (score 0):

The problem that the images don't deploy is the docker-compose.yml file does not set the `image` option. It only set the build `option` to build the images. But when the images are pushed into the ACR. You don't need to build the images again, just need to pull the images with the image `option`. See the example in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/tutorial-docker-compose) you found:

```
version: '3'
services:
  azure-vote-back:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/oss/bitnami/redis:6.0.8
    container_name: azure-vote-back
    environment:
      ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
    ports:
        - "6379:6379"

  azure-vote-front:
    build: ./azure-vote
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/azure-vote-front:v1
    container_name: azure-vote-front
    environment:
      REDIS: azure-vote-back
    ports:
        - "8080:80"
```

You can find that the docker-compose.yml file configures the `image` to set the image name and use the `build` option to build the images. So try to add the image option in the docker-compose.yml file.